# Retrieve children that are objects without single values firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't even simply name the problem to look for it in google, I just want to retrieve all parents without single attributes which is in my case id.

[image]

The code works perfectly without taking id so somehow I have to manage to "skip" it from iterating in the loop.
My code:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Sports").child("Football");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
            if(snapshot1 is not an instanceof Football class)
            Football match = snapshot1.getValue(Football.class);
            String text = match.date + " " + match.place + " " + match.numMates;
            arrayList.add(text);
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to skip the loop?

Comment: well I mean to skip iterating throught all non-object in database

Comment: all "1", "2" ale instances of Football class while 'id' is just a single String attribute that breaks my whole program

Comment: You want to reach to id 3, without using iterating loop?

Comment: I want to get ALL children of "Football" except "id"

Comment: But from your image, the child for "3" only has "id". If you want the place, you need to add them.

Comment: Well I can't understand what you mean, to clarify my question on example:

Comment: From code you can see that I want to set to "Football match" snapshot1 value which is Football class. Every child of "Footbal" which is "1", "2", "3" is a Football object. Then we can see 1 single value which is "id" with a value of 3. I cant assign "id" a Football class as it is a single string so I don't want to iterate through it, I just want to get "1", "2", "3" children to assign its value to Football match.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also: don't leave `onCancelled` empty please. At its minimum it should be something like `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Please add the content of your "Football" class, and please also include the structure of your "1", "2" or "3" node. Please respond with @AlexMamo